# Difference between Phonegap and Phonegap Build?

Tags: cordova, mobile, phonegap-build

What are the differences if any ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Phonegap Build is "in the cloud" and makes it easy to build all targets at once. You just upload your html/css/js in a zip file and they build it on all supported platforms. You can then upload the resulting binaries to the appropriate app stores.

Phonegap runs on your desktop and you are required to have the development tool of the environment you want to compile for. So for iOS you need XCode installed. This allows for more configuration control and more access to plugins at the cost of more complexity.